# Build script doesn't copy all files with babel

Tags: build, babeljs, npm-package

I want to create, for the first time, a npm package from a react component. I'm following this tutorial [here](https://hackernoon.com/creating-a-library-of-react-components-using-create-react-app-without-ejecting-d182df690c6b)

But when I try the build script, I have some error. Because I'm working on windows/vscode powershell terminal, I changed rm-rf to del/s/q/f and installed cross-env.

```
"build": "del/s/q/f dist && cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel src/lib --out-dir dist --copy-files"
```

Now it partially worked but many files are missing in dist folder.

**Here is the error msg**

```
ReferenceError: [BABEL] src\lib\components\DatePicker.jsx: Unknown option: C:\Users\romai\Workspace\Openclassrooms\Frontend\HRNet\hrnet_react_datepicker\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\index.js.overrides. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.

A common cause of this error is the presence of a configuration options object without the corresponding preset name. Example:

Invalid:
  `{ presets: [{option: value}] }`
Valid:
  `{ presets: [['presetName', {option: value}]] }`

For more detailed information on preset configuration, please see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins#pluginpresets-options. (While processing preset: "C:\\Users\\romai\\Workspace\\Openclassrooms\\Frontend\\HRNet\\hrnet_react_datepicker\\node_modules\\babel-preset-react-app\\index.js")
    at Logger.error (C:\Users\romai\Workspace\Openclassrooms\Frontend\HRNet\hrnet_react_datepicker\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\logger.js:41:11)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\Users\romai\Workspace\Openclassrooms\Frontend\HRNet\hrnet_react_datepicker\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:226:20)
    at C:\Users\romai\Workspace\Openclassrooms\Frontend\HRNet\hrnet_react_datepicker\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:265:14
    at C:\Users\romai\Workspace\Openclassrooms\Frontend\HRNet\hrnet_react_datepicker\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:323:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (C:\Users\romai\Workspace\Openclassrooms\Frontend\HRNet\hrnet_react_datepicker\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:275:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (C:\Users\romai\Workspace\Openclassrooms\Frontend\HRNet\hrnet_react_datepicker\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:264:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\Users\romai\Workspace\Openclassrooms\Frontend\HRNet\hrnet_react_datepicker\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:249:14)
    at OptionManager.init (C:\Users\romai\Workspace\Openclassrooms\Frontend\HRNet\hrnet_react_datepicker\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:368:12)
    at File.initOptions (C:\Users\romai\Workspace\Openclassrooms\Frontend\HRNet\hrnet_react_datepicker\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:212:65)
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command npm run build" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

**Here is the src structure**

[image]

**Here is my current builded dist folder**

[image]

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["react-app", { "absoluteRuntime": false }]
  ]
}
```

**Actual package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "README.md"
  ],
  "private": false,
  "description": "datepicker component for personnal openclassrooms hrnet project",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/xxx"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "del/s/q/f dist && cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel src/lib --out-dir dist --copy-files",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.49.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I got this error too, and decided to start debugging. It seems that the problem is that babel-preset-react-app/create.js returns an object containing "overrides", which the babel option-manager.js mergeOptions then says it doesn't know because it's not in the default config.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and decided to debug. This debugging lead me to create.js in node_modules/babel-preset-react-app, which contains "overrides". This is the key that is being rejected. Commenting that part out gives the following error:

```
Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel. (While processing preset: "blabla/frontend/shared/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js")
```

This lead me to brave-search "babel-cli 7", which gives https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli.

A note here states `Note: Please install @babel/cli and @babel/core first before npx babel, otherwise npx will install out-of-dated babel 6.x. Other than npx, you can also drop it inside of an npm run script or you may instead execute with the relative path instead. ./node_modules/.bin/babel`

Notice it states @babel/cli. Looking at package-lock.json, I see babel-cli. Removing that one and installing @babel/cli gave me version 7.

TLDR: uninstall babel-cli, install @babel/cli.